# как при наведении на блок работал hover для другого

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function show(state){
  document.getElementById('window').style.display = state;       document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state;  
}
```

```css
 #wrap{
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.725);
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: auto;
 }
 
 #window{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 16px;
 }
 
 .close{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 364px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s linear;
  background-image: url(close.png);
  background-position: center center;
  border-radius: 34px;
 }
 
 .close:hover{
  background-color: gray;
  background-image: url(close_white.png);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 34px;
 }
```

```html
<div onclick="show('none')" id="wrap"></div>
   <div id="window">
    <div class="close" onclick="show('none')">cl</div>
    <img  style="margin: 20px 0 0 50px;" src="http://sergey-oganesyan.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ipad.png">    
   </div>
  <center><button class="myButton" onclick="show('block')">Показать окно</button></center>
```

как при наведении на блок с `id='wrap'` работал `:hover` для блока с атрибутом `class='close'`  cl - это будет вместо close.png и close-white.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.close:hover, #wrap:hover + #window .close {
    background-color: gray;
    background-image: url(close_white.png);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 34px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Первый ответ и сразу же робочий! Через две минуты будет доступно выбор лучшего ответа)

Comment: Только я  не понимаю заче нужно это - `#window .close` у меня же уже есть `.close `

Comment: Ага уже понял, на личном опыте)